# launch a system command via Javascript in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute a local program on my computer via Javascript in Chrome. In Firefox, it can be done as follows

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath(cmd);

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Can you please any one help me to execute local program from chrome extension?

Thanks

Comment: That's not possible with the regular Chrome extension APIs. You need to use [NPAPI](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) for that. Many recommend the [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) framework for this purpose. I don't have first-hand experience with this, so I can't provide any code.

Comment: Hi Rob,
  Can you please let me know, is there any tutorial to create the NPAPI plugin and also how to integrate the these plugins into the chrome extension?
Thanks

Comment: Like I said, I have never created a NPAPI plugin before. Any anwer I give would be found by doing research. The [NPAPI tag on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npapi?sort=votes) is dedicated to such questions. I suggest to have a look at them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I launch a system command via Javascript in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537772/how-can-i-launch-a-system-command-via-javascript-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Chrome's sandbox security model doesn't let you arbitrarily execute programs on the user's machine; that could be extremely dangerous. It would be theoretically possible to do this using [NPAPI](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html), but it's unlikely that such a plugin would be approved for the Chrome Web Store. If this is only for private use you could create a plugin using NPAPI and then do whatever you want, you just wouldn't be able to distribute the plugin through the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Hi Ken Liu,

Can you please let me know is there any online or offline tutorial to create the NPAPI plugin?
And also please let me know how should i integrate these NPAPI plugins into my chrome extension?

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: **NPAPI** Plugin support for extension has been [discontinued](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html). The documentation has been preserved for historical purposes only.

Answer (score -3):

You can call an jQuery ajax process in order to execute a php script, that can execute commands using exec(). Javascript is a client-side language, but you can use jQuery...

You can find out how in this link:

http://www.sitepoint.com/take-command-ajax/

Comment: This would only be a viable approach if the user of the extension were running a PHP server on his computer. The question asks how to run a command on the *client* computer, not a server.

Comment: That's correct apsillers, the idea was execute a server-side script, can be PHP, ASP, etc

Comment: Running a server-side script is unrelated to what the OP wants to do. The OP wants an extension to launch an executable that sits *on the client machine*. For example, having an executable run `C:\Windows\notepad.exe` on the user's machine and having the user see that program open on his computer -- no servers involved.

Comment: Or are you actually suggesting that the OP require each user of the extension to install a PHP server (and PHP script that calls `exec()`) on their client machine? If so, you should make that more clear in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Chrome is more secure with this kind of scripts, because of the possibility of executing malware.